# MS Access VBA Changing the content of the expression builder based on user definition

Tags: ms-access

Is there a way to change the content of the expression builder in a query based on user pref.. for example the user chooses item A from a combobox, after choosing item A, the corresponding code for Item A populates the expression builder in query1 on a single field... ive tried putting it in a function and putting the function in the expression builder but the expression is treated as text. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use Eval() function in query for evaluating data/calculations selected in combobox.

Comment: Nice suggestion on the eval() function... but i cant seem to make it work. Ive stored the code of the expression builder (code goes like - if (field 1 = field 2, matched,unmatched) in a table field. Now when the user chooses the corresponding id for the code. It populates the remarks field in the query. The prob is im having an error on eval() ...

Comment: Eval has some limitations for evaluation, for instance it won't recognize field name inside expression. So, it would be better to change the logic of query in order to avoid Eval-like solution. For instance you can add few additional fields with different calculations and in the "main" field use Switch() function for selecting additional field with appropriate calculation depending on user choice. In most of cases you can also avoid creating additional fields using iif() and Switch() functions. Everything depends on required logic. We can offer something if you give more details with example.